# Fiddler TLS version details

Tags: .net, fiddler

Our payment provider is turning off TLS1.0.

The Asp.Net Application runs on .Net Framework 4.0 and searching online found an article that i can do a register key change to force default tls protocol to TLS1.2 by following the information on this link - http://joymonscode.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/how-to-make-net-40-45-use-tls-12.html

Monitoring traffic on fiddler i can still see TLS1.0 but why the response section shows TLS1.2.

I am not sure if we connected to payment provider over TLS1.2 or 1.0. (see attached image for more info.)

[image]

Can someone please clarify ?

Comment: Related questions: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/32790/29543 and https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26059/29543. The ServerHello might just be ignoring the ClientHello message's version and dictating that the protocol must be TLS 1.2, so it proceeds from there with that protocol. Why the client isn't sending 1.2 to begin with...I'm not sure. Maybe it's sending 1.0 to be most compatible?

Comment: .NET 4.0 does not support TLS1.2. You could hack it with a registry key editing and a forced SecurityProtocol enum if the machine where the application is running has a .net 4.5 System.dll. Otherwise, .net 4.0 doesn't know how to "talk" TLS 1.2. The whole story about those registry settings: [TLS/SSL Settings - MSDN Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786418(v=ws.11)#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS12). What I can see from your picture is that TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA is one of the ciphers, compatible with TLS1.2 for both client and server.

Answer (score 3):

to change the tls version go to tools->options->https click on protocols and change 1.0 to 1.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Jimi
Thanks for your answer. I'm working with user1754675 on this problem, and we have added quite a few registry keys in that SChannel registry branch from your linked article. All of the standards (SSL2, SSL3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, and TLS1.2) have DisabledByDefault set to 0, and Enabled set to 0xffffffff

Comment: If all protocols are allowed, you have to check whether the GAC includes al least .NET 4.5 (.NET 4.6.1 would be better if the platform supports it). Then (if you can't recompile) force the `ServicePointManager` to include TLS 1.2 among the protocols used in the SSL handshake: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (...) | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;` where the "magic" 3072 is simply the numeric value of the enum corresponding to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`, since .NET 4.0 does not offer that choice.